# How to use template within Django template?

Tags: python, html, django, templates, django-1.4

I have the django template like below:

```
<a href="https://example.com/url{{ mylist.0.id }}" target="_blank"><h1 class="title">{{ mylist.0.title }}</h1></a>
<p>
{{ mylist.0.text|truncatewords:50 }}<br>
...
```

(the actual template is quite big)

It should be used 10 times on the same page, but 'external' html elements are different:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 block block-color-1">
    *django template here - mylist.0, truncatewords:50 *
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 block block-color-2">
    *django template here - mylist.1, truncatewords:15 *
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 block block-color-3">
    *django template here - mylist.2, truncatewords:30 *
  </div>
</div>
...
```

Looks like even usage of `for` with considering `first`, `last`, odd and even elements will not simplify the task.

What can I do to have the template (given in the beginning) defined only once?

Comment: Have you tried `{% include %}`?

Comment: @Wtower, I am not sure how to use `include` since different list elements should be used (see `mylist.0`, `mylist.1` etc.) and different `truncatewords` values (`50`, `15` and `30`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include) tag in order to supply the included template with a consistent variable name:

For example:

*parent.html*

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 block block-color-1">
        {% include 'templates/child.html' with list_item=mylist.0 t=50 only %}
    </div>
</div>
```

*child.html*

```
{{ list_item.text|truncatewords:t }}
```

*UPDATE*: As **spectras** recommended, you can use the *with* and *only* keywords within the tag in order to supply the included template with the necessary context.

Comment: using the `with` tag in that fashion is a clever idea. +1 from me.

Comment: Actually, I think it's much better to do this instead: `{% include 'templates/child.html' with list_item=mylist.0 t=50 only %}` This makes the given variable accessible to the template, and the `only` keyword hides everything else. It's better if the sub-template does not access the parent context, for re-use and encapsulation.

Comment: This is quite a good one @spectras, never noticed this. Updating, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an include tag for that. It's part of the built-in tags: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include

If you need to do something more complicated, you can always write your own template tags: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/